# Why are my @font-face declarations not working?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have been provided with a load of fonts a designer would like placing into my website. The site is located at example.com/SITE_DIRECTORY/WordPress_ROOT.

Using font-face declarations I have implemented the fonts into the site like this:

```
/* Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Circular";
    src:    url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/Circular-Std-Bold.otf') format('opentype');
    src:    url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/circular_bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/circular_bold.woff') format('woff'),
            url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/circular_bold.ttf')  format('truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Circular";
    src:    url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/Circular-Std-Medium.otf') format('opentype');
    src:    url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/circular_medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/circular_medium.woff') format('woff'),
            url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/circular_medium.ttf')  format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Proximanova";
    src:    url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/proximanova_bold.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Proximanova";
    src:    url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/pproximanova_semibold.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Proximanova";
    src:    url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/proximanova_regular.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Proximanova";
    src:    url('/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/proximanova_light.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: "Circular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

body,
p,
a,
input,
textarea,
button,
input[type=text],
input[type=submit] {
    font-family: "Circular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* END Fonts */
```

I can see the CSS represents what I have written, and if I navigate to:

```
example.co.uk/wp-content/themes/clickiest/fonts/Circular-Std-Bold.otf
```

My font file is downloaded.

Why are my fonts not displaying?

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path (relative to the stylesheet)?

Comment: Forward slash goes from root though?

Comment: Sometimes doesn't work properly in stylesheets

Comment: I will give it a go!

Comment: Also if it's the proxi font not working in ie11, i think ie11 doesn't support woff2

Comment: @pete - I had to adjust my src to represent the URL of the main website. This is being built in a subdirectory of the site. example.com/website_root/wp-content... I was under the impression the new root for this sub site would be automatically re-assigned to the sub site. That is not the case. Adding the pre-site directories has fixed the issue.

Comment: @Pete - if you could write an answer explaining what we have highlighted above I can accept your answer. Thanks for the help!